# How can I structure my models better for data access which uses an SQL View in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm always looking for better ways to do things and one thing I really want to improve is the manner in which I use SQL views in my ASP.NET Core application and how they are structured in my models.

Why are you using SQL views?

Ok, some of the data in my system is so complex that joining and creating sub queries using LINQ wouldn't be practical and would also be a client side event I'd prefer to avoid.  Views provide a manner to return data and have it read from a service with a minimum of fuss and the required joins and subqueries are all in place.

Take this basic view as an example, let's call it `ViewCarHires`, this has been stripped down for the purposes of this question

```
SELECT c.[Id], c.[CarMake], c.[CarModel], h.[HideDate]
FROM Cars AS c
LEFT JOIN Hires AS h ON h.[CarId] = c.[Id]
```

All this does is left join the `Hires` table to the `Cars` table based on the `Id`.

In my application I have two entity classes:

***Cars.cs***

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string CarMake { get; set; }
public string CarModel { get; set; }
```

***Hires.cs***

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
public int CarId { get; set; }
```

What I typically do is create a view model that has all the data I am returning from my SQL view.

For example:

```
[Table("ViewCarHires")]
public class ViewCarHires 
{
    // Cars
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CarMake { get; set; }
    public string CarModel { get; set; }

    // Hires
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
    public int CarId { get; set; }
}
```

I can then inject this service into my application and access the joined data without the need to make any linq statements.

The above is just a demo but you'll see that, in my view model I have had to declare not only the `Cars.cs` fields but also the `Hires.cs` fields, my question is, is there a better way to do this without the need to write every single column name again?  In the interest of not repeating myself, if I change one or many column(s) in the Cars.cs table I'd need to go into this view model and change them here too.

It's one of those design choices that feels long winded and something that could be done better. So, how do I bring in the columns I need without writing everything twice?

Comment: Copy paste. View is another entity which you have to define from scratch.

Comment: If JSON can be good as result, one of the options is to return JSON from view with [Json returning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). and directly return JSON object to clients, with this approach, the process will deliver on the client-side.